# Drools not load rules from /resources

Tags: java, classloader, drools, kie, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a project in Java + Drools.
It works great, but the thing is that the rules are located in a separate jar file. Worked even from the terminal. I moved all these rules to the main project in the resources folder, keeping the package structure. Changed nothing else.
When I run the app in Intellij Idea everything works fine.
But when I build the jar file via spring-boot-maven-plugin, and run it in the terminal, the application does not see the rules.
I managed to find out that the problem occurs due to the fact that the Idea uses the default class loader, and when launched from the terminal, the LaunchedURLClassLoader (from spring) one is used.

Tell me where to put the files, or how to set up a pom file so that the rules are loaded from the resources folder?

Java 11,
Drools version 7.37.0.Final,
Spring 2.6.3

pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

//...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${drools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
```

kmodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="foo" packages="drools.foo" default="true">
        <ksession name="fooSession">
        </ksession>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Config Class

```
    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {
        return KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
    }

    @Bean
    public KieBase kieBase(KieContainer kieContainer) {
        return kieContainer.getKieBase();
    }
```

**UPD: Resolved. Delete
`<executable>true</executable>`
from spring-boot-maven-plugin**

Comment: Please show your directory structure in your `src/main/resources` directory. Where does that kmodule.xml live, physically, and what are the other directories? Where are your DRL files?

Comment: The .drl files are in src/main/resources/drools/foo/*.drl, kmodule.xml - src/main/resources/META-INF. From what I have found so far: ZipKieModule.processZipEntries(ZipInputStream zipIn, ZipEntry entry, String rootFolder) has returner empty "entry". ZipInputStream.readLOC() return null of get32(tmpbuf, 0) != LOCSIG)

Comment: Resolved. Delete ```<executable>true</executable>``` from spring-boot-maven-plugin.
 Roddy, thanks for the help

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, is there a way to use with ```<executable>true</executable>```?